# ADF Oracle: SelectionListener not firing when the first row is selected in a table

Tags: jsf, oracle-adf

In the table,

1. When clicking the first row, the selectionListener can be not invoked. but clicking the others row, the selectionListener can be invoked.
2. After clicking clicking the others row, go back to click the first row, the selectionListener can be invoked.

What is the wrong with the selectionListener?

Answer (score 4):

That is nothing wrong with that, it is just that after rendering the table the first row of the table is ALREADY SELECTED. You might think about a cursor, that changes position each time you select a row within the table. This action triggers the event caught by the selectionListener. But when a page first loads or is refreshed, the cursor is already positioned at the first row. It is autoselected So no action -> no event 
Check this post to find an alternative: [ADF Table SelectionListener on first row](https://community.oracle.com/thread/2280505)